# FCKeditor 1 validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am using FCKeditor to upload data in database

Code is as follows..

```
<?php
    // Automatically calculates the editor base path based on the _samples directory.
    // This is usefull only for these samples. A real application should use something like this:
    // $oFCKeditor->BasePath = '/fckeditor/' ;  // '/fckeditor/' is the default value.
    $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;
    $sBasePath = substr( $sBasePath, 0, strpos( $sBasePath, "_samples" ) ) ;
    $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1') ;
    $oFCKeditor->Height = 400;
    $oFCKeditor->BasePath   = $sBasePath ;
    $oFCKeditor->Value= "";
    $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
?>
```

And Javascript for Validation that not allowed the data field empty used is as follows..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validatearticle() {
    if (document.addtwebinar_frm.FCKeditor1.value == "")
       {
          alert("Please Enter Article Data!");
          document.addtwebinar_frm.FCKeditor1.focus();
          return false;  
       }
    }
    </script>
```

This javascript portion shown is a part of script. Other Values And validation e.g. Article Subject, Article Writer etc. in same form are getting validated. But even after keeping fckeditor field blank, form gets submitted.

please help on code or javascript.

Comment: try to check with length

Answer (score 0):

Try [trimming](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) the text to remove any whitespace.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatearticle() {
if (document.addtwebinar_frm.FCKeditor1.value.trim() === "")
   {
      alert("Please Enter Article Data!");
      document.addtwebinar_frm.FCKeditor1.focus();
      return false;  
   }
}
</script>
```